# Actual CSS Responsive background not being responsive (?)

Tags: html, css, mobile, background

I am building a website and I'm stuck to a problem:
the background stretches in Google Chrome developers tools in lower/higher resolutions. 
When I open the website directly from my mobile phone the background does not fit in the screen and it just "cut" the background.

Here is the website: https://feargames.emilianomaccaferri.me [remove if spam]
And here is my background css:

```
body {
background: url(../assets/bg.png);
max-width:none
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color:#464646;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

Dunno what is going on here.

Comment: Works fine on my mobile device .. Check your mobile device settings and make sure you're not in "Desktop" mode ...

Comment: Same - it actually cut off  the first time, but once I rotated the screen and back, it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: obviously a setting with you mobile device .. Not your responsive design ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an issue with auto fixing CSS in some browsers. I noticed that your max-width property doesn't end with a semi-colon. Some browsers will not show anything after due to running into a syntax error.